# How to switch views in routing? Can we call a directive in templateUrl of routeProvider?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

I want to switch a view based on a flag (flag will be set at the time of user login in cookies) while routing.

Something like that:

```
$routeProvider.when("/editTest/:ID",
                       {                              
                           templateUrl: 
                               {
                                   load: function (pageView, $location) {
                                       return pageView.get();
                                   }
                               },
                           controller: 'EditTestController'
                       });
```

The Directive:

```
DashboardModule.factory("pageView", function ($http, $cookieStore, $rootScope, $timeout) {
return {
    get: function () {
        $rootScope.formView = $cookieStore.get("cformview");
        if ($rootScope.formView == "tabView") {
            window.location = '/apps/templates/editTest.html';
        }
        else {
            window.location = '/apps/templates/editTestPageView.html';
        }
    }
};});
```

So, when user gets login and clicks on link, page will redirect or open based on flag.

Comment: A more elegant why to achieve this, would be using transitions:
https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/docs/latest/modules/transition.html
You define a transition in the config block of the module.
There you can do something like:

$transitionsProvider.onBefore({
    from: 'tabView'
  }, (transition) => {
    return transition.router.stateService.target('editTest');
}
This wont be the whole solution but maybe an idea.
Nevertheless using window.location is not what you want in a SPA/PWA because it reinitialises the whole app.

Comment: yes, you may be right. But I solved it as to Get a flag as params from the route and use it in "templateUrl" like a condition.
" templateUrl: function (params) {
               return params.flagTab == '7A8p@NeL' ? "tabView.html" : "pageView.html";
           },"

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by using flag from route para in "templateUrl" like a condition. And on condition base, did routing.

```
    $routeProvider.when('/PageManifest/:flagTab',
               {
                   resolve: {
                       load: function (ShareData, $location) {
                           return ShareData.getPermission('GetPerCookie');
                       }
                   },

                   templateUrl: function (params) {
                       return params.flagTab == 'flagValue' ? "tabView.html" : "pageView.html";
                   },
                   controller: 'PageController'
               });
```